# Retrieving User Membership from Access VBA Using ADO to Perform LDAP Query

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory, ldap, ado

I am querying Active Directory using VBA from Microsoft Access. Like many examples posted online, I am using a ADO connection to perform an LDAP query. I can successfully pull some attributes, like `sn`,`givenName`,`mail`, `proxyAddresses` and some of the miscellaneous MS Exchange properties like the `msExchExtensionAttribute##` properties.

Now I am trying to query the `memberOf` attribute and am receiving no return value for any user other than myself. I can easily see other user's group memberships in Outlook or see who is the member of groups by doing a search using the Windows Active Directory search tool. Sounds to me like a permissions issue, so I dug into my connection string. I had a suspicion that I was making my request anonymously since I did not specify a username or password.

I am trying to ensure I use Windows authentication and this must be able to be run by an average user (as I am on this domain as well), so no admin powers will be available to do this.

Some basic rummaging around led me to believe that setting the Integrated Security property of the connection properties to `SSPI` should do it. That doesn't work, though. At this point, I'm just trying to get it to work, so the function is only returning a string for debug, but I'll eventually return an array or object.

Here's what I've got so far:

```vb
Function GetMembershipFromUsername(uname As String) As String
    'Get the domain root
    Dim root As IADs
    Set root = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

    'Set the query parameters
    Dim base as String, fltr as String, attr as String, scope as String
    base = "<LDAP://" & root.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
    fltr = "(&(objectCLass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=" & uname & "))"
    attr = "sAMAccountName,memberOf"
    scope = "subtree"

    'Connect to the LDAP server
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Properties.Item("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"
    conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    'Create LDAP command object
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    'Build command
    cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

    'Execute and return info
    Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset, vi as Variant, ml as String
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        For Each vi In rs.Fields(1).Value
            ml = ml & vi & Chr(10)
        Next vi
    End If
    rs.Close

    conn.Close

    GetMembershipFromUsername = ml
End Function
```

Am I running into a permissions issue, am I somehow still making my request anonymously, or am I making some other mistake that would only allow me to pull my own group membership?

Comment: What value is your function returning right now?

Comment: It returns an array of variants for myself and `Null` for anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

The [IADsOpenDSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsopendsobject) interface should be used instead of IADs for binding to AD objects using a security context other than the one of the user currently requesting the binding.

> The IADsOpenDSObject interface is designed to supply a security
>   context for binding to an object in the underlying directory store. It
>   provides a means for specifying credentials of a client. Use this
>   interface to bind to an ADSI object when you must supply a set of
>   credentials for authentication in any directory service.

You'll need to create a reference to IADsOpenDSObject using `GetObject()` method, just as you do with an IADs interface. You can then call the [`OpenDSObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsopendsobject-opendsobject) method that allows to bind to an ADSI object using arbitrary credentials :

```
Dim ds As IADsOpenDSObject 
Set ds = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

Dim root As IADs
Set root = ds.OpenDSObject(dn, username, password, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)
```

The last parameter is an authentication flag (see [`ADS_AUTHENTICATION_ENUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsopendsobject)) that determines which authentication process to use.

Comment: I tried adding the `ds` object before getting my root. `Set ds = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")` fails, but `Set ds = GetObject("LDAP:")` appears on other forums and succeeds. I then pull the root DSE via `Set root = ds.OpenDSObject("LDAP://RootDSE", vbNullString, vbNullString, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)` which also succeeds, but then I always get `Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified error` and cannot query the domain for anything. Feel like I missed something in your instructions, but also feel like this is the right direction after reading the linked docs...

Comment: So... Don't know what I did the first time around wrong, but I managed to get it to not fire the error from before. `ds.OpenDSObject` works now, but I still get the same problem I started with - an empty membership.

Comment: It depends.. I think it's normal to get the same result using your own account credentials. `OpenDSObject` allows precisely to bind to an ADSI object using an arbitrary (i.e. *elevated*) account. Typically, applications are "authorized" via a manager account (provided the user authentication succeeds in the first place) or uses a different authentication provider. Try using a manager account to bind to adsi objects, if you don't get the expected result it could be that it's not a permission issue.